# データフレームで１つの列の要素の一部に１０を掛けたい

Tags: python

以下のようなデータフレーム（変数名を"df"としています）の"close"と"open"列の3行目以降に10を掛けたようなデータフレームを取得したいのですが、python3ではどのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？

ひどく初心者的な質問で大変申し訳ありませんが、どなたかご教示いただけましたら幸いです。どうぞよろしくお願いします！

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のようにすると元のデータフレームの"close"と"open"列の3行目以降の値が、元々の値に10を掛けた値に更新されます(動作はpython 3.7.2, pandas 0.23.4で確認してます)。

```
import pandas as pd

# 仮のデータ
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,1,2],[2,2,3],[3,3,4],[4,4,5]],
    columns=['hoge','close', 'open']
)

# カラム名から行番号を取得
i = df.columns.get_loc('close')
j = df.columns.get_loc('open')

# 3行目以降の、closeおよびopen列の値を更新
df.iloc[2: ,[i, j]] = df.iloc[2: ,[i, j]].apply(lambda x: x * 10)
```

また、もともとのデータフレームは更新したくない、ということであれば、`df2 = df.copy()`でデータフレームをいったんコピーしてから、df2に対して上記の操作をするとよいです。

以下も参考にしてください。

`get_loc()` : [pandas.DataFrameの行番号、列番号を取得 \| note.nkmk.me](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-get-loc-row-column-num/)
`iloc()` : [pandasで任意の位置の値を取得・変更するat, iat, loc, iloc \| note.nkmk.me](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-at-iat-loc-iloc/)
`apply()` : [pandasで要素、行、列に関数を適用するmap, applymap, apply \| note.nkmk.me](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-map-applymap-apply/)

Answer (score 2):

`df`を直接変更してよければ

```py
df["close"][2:] *= 10
df["open"][2:] *= 10
```

とできます。